# Running python in terminal without suffix

Tags: python, terminal, file-extension

I feel like this is incredibly easy to fix, but for some reason it isn't.

I want to run a program in linux that opens python file filename.py by writing:

> python3 filename arg

but it only works if i write:

> python3 filename.py arg

Is there an easy way to run it without adding the extension? And without removing the extension completely? I wouldn't have imagined this to be a problem at all, but here we are. 
Thankful for help!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Why? Also, what if there's a file named "filename" (without `.py`) in the same directory? Also, does `python3 -m filename arg` solve your problem?

Comment: python3: can't open file 'isConnected': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I'm certain I'm in the right directory though!

Answer (score 1):

Your file is called `filename.py`, therefore you call it with `python3 filename.py`. If you want to call it with `python3 filename`, you'll need to rename the file.

The one thing you can do is call Python with the `-m` switch, which will try to import a module with that name, i.e. `python3 -m filename`. That should work without renaming the file.

Comment: Hah. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my assignment then! The requirements state that what i described should be possible but after all the time I've spent on it I feel like you're right. Guess there's a typo or something somewhere! Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you start your python script with the shebang, then you won't need to type 'python3' before the filename each time you wish to run the code.

```
`#!/usr/bin/env python3'
```

Secondly, if you create a setup.py file is the same directory. Then you can install your script locally using:
`$ sudo pip3 install -e .`
from within your directory.

You will then be able to run your script from anywhere within terminal using: 
`$ myscript args`

More info on creating a setup file here: https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/tutorials/distributing-packages/#setup-py

and example setup file here: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py